# Create an MD5 hash of an entire DB row to use as a key?

Tags: php, mysql, database, hash

I have a foreign database that I need to replicate in-house. The DB is hosted by an, uncooperative, vendor. So I have little control over it. I do have the ability to write report reports that I call via API to bring the data down as I move them into a local Oracle DB. However, several of the tables do NOT have unique fields, I can't add one, and in fact, after some investigation it appears the only way to get a unique field is to concatenate the entire row which is not desirable for obvious reasons. I can, however, execute PHP script on the report as its called, so my idea was to create an MD5 hash of the entire row and store that at the beginning of the table as the key.

I realize that it's possible to have collisions but they should be very rare. Given the pitfalls of not having a key, I'd prefer losing a record every few million rows than having thousands of duplicates should we ever have to reflow the DB. Are there any other pitfalls of this method I should be worried about? I'm trying to make the best of a bad situation, I realize that this isn't a perfect solution. I just want to make sure I give my boss the best information regarding the pitfalls of this so we're not suprised down the road. And yes, the vendors getting dumped, that's why we're replicating the DB.

Comment: Why do you need such a key while you cannot use it to identify the external row. When some of the fields are modified in the external database you will get for the 'same' row a different key. Or will the data never change in the row of the external database?

Comment: Why you need a unique field if you can insert row by row into the new database where you also have no primary key in the table?

Comment: They're log files. Insert only, no updates. Otherwise, yes, I'd agree, this wouldn't work. But since the records never change the key should be accurate unless the vendor does something evil with the records. I'm trying to make the best of a bad situation here.

Comment: We did use the MD5 as a key and it did work. There are some situations during reflows that will result in duplicate records, but that's far better than the alternative... which would have caused far more duplicates. It's not a perfect solution but it's the best we could do.